# Open lightbox like image gallery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to open lightbox onclick with multiple image
for example I have a php loop which displays the barcode of the products. All barcode have (under) muti images. like some barcode have 3 image some 2 some 5. I am trying when I click on barcode lightbox popup open  and all the images under this barcode are show as a group. if user click other barcode than images come related to that barcode. I am spending more than one hour but I am failed please help me. If there is alternative of lightbox please let me know. how i get this 'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4044/4286199901_33844563eb.jpg',) link throgh php
in val i have barcode. how i send to php file and get the image links and show here where example links are shown.

```
function opengallrey(val){
    $.fancybox([
            'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4044/4286199901_33844563eb.jpg',
            'http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2687/4220681515_cc4f42d6b9.jpg',
            {
                'href'  : 'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4213562882_851e92f326.jpg',
                'title' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit'
            }
        ], {
            'padding'           : 0,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'type'              : 'image',
            'changeFade'        : 0
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://fancybox.net/

try this one it works same as lightbox